# HTML templating framework that lets you include partials without javascript?

Tags: html, templates, template-engine

When designing in code I often times have the need for an element across several pages, like a menu for instance, and I'd like to store it in a template. If I'm using Jade I can include that template into any file and the command line Jade compiler will spit it back out. I don't have to write any JavaScript or pass context or anything, I just get the templated markup.

Is there a tool that offers this same functionality but with plain HTML? Without requiring a server of some kind and without requiring a bunch of JS functions? I've looked at Mustache, Handlebars and Underscore but they all require that I turn the template into a function and call it with a context. I just need to replicate HTML on multiple pages.

**update**

To clarify, I'm looking for a command line tool to compile partials in an html file

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for templated HTML, without using any server-side logic, and without any logic on the client-side (ie: JS), then the answer is no.

Really, at that point, you're left with copy/paste.

HTML is 100% static, and you can only request one URL at a time, so you're left with one single static page.

If I misunderstood, and you want to know how you might template in JS, but want something simpler, where your template downloads the HTML template, reads through it and fills in the blanks... or if you're looking to template in some other language on the server-side, then feel free to correct me.

Comment: jade has a command line compiler that you can run which will find all of your includes and add them into your file as html. I'm looking for something like that.

Comment: I get that. But something like that in JS, something like that in PHP, in Ruby, in Python... ?  In a CMS, in an IDE? Because you need to use a language or a tool of some sort, to do it. I'm not suggesting NodeJS solutions, because you've already got Jade, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Oh I don't care what language it's written in. If it uses Node then so be it. Members on my team aren't comfortable writing Jade but want to be able to write little partials that they include in their html files. Then we use the command line to compile it all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/).

- > deploy anywhere – it’s just HTML, no special server stuff required
- > Webby is a fantastic little website management system. It would be
  >   called a content management system if it were a bigger kid. But, it’s
  >   just a runt with a special knack for transforming text. And that’s
  >   really all it does – manages the legwork of turning text into
  >   something else, an ASCII Alchemist if you will.
  >
  > Webby works by combining the contents of a page with a layout to
  >   produce HTML. The layout contains everything common to all the pages –
  >   HTML headers, navigation menu, footer, etc. – and the page contains
  >   just the information for that page. You can use your favorite markup
  >   language to write your pages; Webby supports quite a few.